# FTP an image over a TCP/IP wireless connection from a Windows Mobile 6 device

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, ftp, tcp

I have a mobile application that needs to FTP an image over a wireless TCP/IP connection to a server. I have searched the internet for resources only to find that some of the popular ways to do this are not supported by the dot net compact framework (such as System.Runtime.Remoting). Is using TCP/IP a viable solution or is there another way to do this?

Thank you ahead of time,

Zach Smith

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a connection, something like [this](http://aspalliance.com/1187_Building_a_Simple_FTP_Application_Using_C_20.all) should work.